# Lazy Load collection list with filters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy load my collection list with filters in Javascript.
The normal lazy loading works perfectly (without filtering).
The only issue I am having is that whenever I am selecting a filter the results all still have their lazy load classes applied.

I am checking the url for search parameters, that are being applied or removed via the filter.

How can I fix this?

```
<script>
 const collectionList = document.querySelector('.swiper-wrapper');
const items = collectionList.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');

let observer;
let currentIndex = 0;
const batchSize = 3;

const showNextBatch = () => {
  const endIndex = currentIndex + batchSize;
  for (let i = currentIndex; i < endIndex && i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
  currentIndex = endIndex;

  if (currentIndex >= items.length) {
    observer.disconnect();
  }
};

const options = {
  rootMargin: '50px 0px',
  threshold: 0.01
};

if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {
  observer = new IntersectionObserver(showNextBatch, options);

  for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
  currentIndex = batchSize;

  for (let i = batchSize; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.add('lazy');
    observer.observe(items[i]);
  }
} else {
  // Fallback for browsers that don't support IntersectionObserver
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
}
  let currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);

setInterval(() => {
  let newUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
  if (currentUrl.search !== newUrl.search) {
    currentUrl = newUrl;
    resetObserver();
  }
}, 250);

const resetObserver = () => {
  observer.disconnect();
  let visibleItems = collectionList.querySelectorAll(':not(.lazy) .swiper-slide');
  for (let i = 0; i < visibleItems.length; i++) {
    if (!visibleItems[i].classList.contains('lazy')) {
      observer.observe(visibleItems[i]);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The .lazy class has the style display: none.

EDIT: So now I have updated the code. The issue is now that it only shows the first 3 elements (the rest still has the lazy class).

```
<script>
const batchSize = 3;

const showNextBatch = () => {
  const endIndex = currentIndex + batchSize;
  for (let i = currentIndex; i < endIndex && i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
  currentIndex = endIndex;

  if (currentIndex >= items.length) {
    observer.disconnect();
  }
};

const options = {
  rootMargin: '50px 0px',
  threshold: 0.01
};

if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {
  let observer;
  let currentIndex = 0;
  observer = new IntersectionObserver(showNextBatch, options);

  let collectionList = document.querySelector('.swiper-wrapper');
  let items = collectionList.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');

  for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
  currentIndex = batchSize;

  for (let i = currentIndex; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.add("lazy");
    observer.observe(items[i]);
  }
  const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
    resetObserver();
  });

  mutationObserver.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  const resetObserver = () => {
    observer.disconnect();
    collectionList = document.querySelector('.swiper-wrapper');
    items = collectionList.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
    }
    currentIndex = batchSize;
    observer = new IntersectionObserver(showNextBatch, options);

    for (let i = currentIndex; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].classList.add("lazy");
      observer.observe(items[i]);
    }
  };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
const collectionList = document.querySelector('.swiper-wrapper');
const items = collectionList.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');

let observer;
let currentIndex = 0;
const batchSize = 3;

const showNextBatch = () => {
  const endIndex = currentIndex + batchSize;
  for (let i = currentIndex; i < endIndex && i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
  currentIndex = endIndex;

  if (currentIndex >= items.length) {
    observer.disconnect();
  }
};

const options = {
  rootMargin: '50px 0px',
  threshold: 0.01
};

if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {
  observer = new IntersectionObserver(showNextBatch, options);

  for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
  currentIndex = batchSize;

  for (let i = batchSize; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.add('lazy');
    observer.observe(items[i]);
  }
} else {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('lazy');
  }
}

let currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);

setInterval(() => {
  let newUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
  if (currentUrl.search !== newUrl.search) {
    currentUrl = newUrl;
    resetObserver();
  }
}, 250);

const resetObserver = () => {
  observer.disconnect();
  let visibleItems = collectionList.querySelectorAll(':not(.lazy) .swiper-slide');
  for (let i = 0; i < visibleItems.length; i++) {
    observer.observe(visibleItems[i]);
  }
};

</script>
```

Comment: Thats not working :/